# Is there a way to simulate medium trust in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, medium-trust

I am looking for "easy button", where I can say run this app under medium trust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

As per: http://blog.mahingupta.com/mahingupta/blog/post/2010/08/01/AspNet-Set-Medium-trust-in-local.aspx

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Medium" />
</system.web>
```

Just note that most hosts do modifications to their medium trust offerings. Usually give few more permissions for LINQ and cross-server calls, but it differs from one host to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure medium trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx#paght000020_step1) - just add a configuration option.

> To configure an application to run with medium trust, add the following element to either the application's specific Web.config file in the application's virtual root directory or to the machine-level Web.config file.
>
> `<trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />`