# using Mysql Connector without installation .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, mysql, entity-framework

I have installed mysql connector to my computer. 
I use EntityFramework. Provider is MySql.Data.MySqlClient.

MyWeb application works well. But I deployed my project to shared hosting.
I got error .

Server Error in '/' Application.
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

And I cant Install MYsql connector to Shared Hosting. 
How can I fix this problem. Without installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add provider library to bin directory in your web application and [register provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705108/mysql-entity-framework-error-the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-t/8709768#8709768) in your web.config.