# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0

Tags: asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, mysql-connector

I'm at a COMPLETE loss - I'm having super wierd issues with what I still really dont even understand... I'm running Entity Framework 4.1, MySql 5.xx and my MySql Connector is v 6.4.4 - everything works beatifully locally however whenever I upload to the server I receive:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

Line 48:         /// Initializes a new proventradesEntities object using the connection string found in the 'proventradesEntities' section of the application configuration file.
Line 49:         /// </summary>
Line 50:         public proventradesEntities() : base("name=proventradesEntities", "proventradesEntities")
Line 51:         {
Line 52:             this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;


Source File: e:\web\proventrade\htdocs\App_Code\ProvenTrades.Designer.cs    Line: 50

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I am SO confused, I am positive that I have MySql 6.4.4 dll's in my Bin directory, also my Web.config makes ZERO references to version 6.3.6 - I've searched my entire project (using global find) for 6.3.6 and even just for MySql to see if I can find ANY random references to this rogue 6.3.6 version but I find nothing!

I'm so lost and am getting no where. I would GREATLY appreciate any guidance on this, thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You could try to redirect the assembly version.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I've forgotten to mention above i've attempted that w/ no success - its so wierd, and driving me nuts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add provider library to bin directory in your web application and [register provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705108/mysql-entity-framework-error-the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-t/8709768#8709768) in your web.config

Then You must download Connector [.Net Mono here](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.5.3-noinstall.zip/from/http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/mysql/).

And put Dlls into bin folder.

Comment: Ok i've added the mysql dll's to my bin directory, is that what you mean by library?

Comment: Also - i've added the .Net Mono connectors to my bin and uploaded. By provider library do you mean the EDMX file? Its not compiled so i just have it in the app_code directory. I'm not sure if I need to use the DbProviderFactories

Comment: Ok my friend - one more update - I've registered the provider - however now the error message states: "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0" instead of the 6.3.6.0 - i think we may be getting closer though!

Comment: Ok - the link you gave me (.net mono) was actually not version 6.4.4 - so i uploaded 6.4.4 after following your instructions and that fixed it!!!!! thank you SO MUCH