# Runtime exception in asp.net at webserver

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have developed an application in ***asp.net*** with ***mysql*** database.
I find an error as:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make sure that all required MySQL assemblies have been correctly added and referenced (e.g. machine.config -> web.config, etc.).
There have been similar issues discussed on SO e.g. 
[Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527303/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-3-6-0)

[Can't load mysql.web assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436446/cant-load-mysql-web-assembl)