# How to deploy Lightswitch app connecting to MySql Database

Tags: mysql, web-config, visual-studio-lightswitch, mysql-connector

I have a simple (no authentication yet) Lightswitch VS 2012 app. That on my local computer connects to a mysql database (the database is hosted by my hosting company). All works well.

I then 'publish' this app to my local IIS server, and copy all that to my hosting companies server.

It mostly works, except the WCF service won't work. Upon connecting to the WCF service directly (the .svc file) I get a 'request error'. The stack trace in the Trace.axd is as follows

```
[Microsoft.LightSwitch.DataService][Application:Error][LightSwitchServiceApplication.vinyldyeData:CreateObjectContext] An exception has occurred:  System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
  at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
  at LightSwitchApplication.Implementation.vinyldyeDataServiceImplementation.CreateObjectContext()
  at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.get_ObjectContext()
```

It looked as though the hosting company just doesn't have the MySQL Connector in the GAC, so i've added this into the bin folder, still get the same error.

I've looked in the Web.configs, and there is no mention of mysql connector, how does the app know which connector to use?

Have you deployed a Lightswitch app to a host using mysql? if so what files am i missing, or config option.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already added the MySQL Connector (I assume 6.4.4) DLLs to the bin folder, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8709768/116047) post.  Worked for me.

Comment: this looks like the trick! I'll give this a go, thank you very much.

Comment: spot on, thank you so much. I must admit, having looked in the web.config I did end up asking myself, how does it 'know' what to load for this!